# How to add data to a particular document in a subcollection in firestore database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

My index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  let action = request.body.result.action;
  var Name = request.body.result.parameters.Name;
  let params = request.body.result.parameters;
  var Answer1 = request.body.result.parameters.Answer1;
  let query = request.body.result.resolvedQuery;

  const parameters = request.body.result.parameters;
  const inputContexts = request.body.result.contexts;

  if (action === 'save.name' || inputContexts == 'welcome' && action === 'save.answer1' || inputContexts == 'question1') {
    admin.firestore().collection('users').doc('Details').collection('MYuser1').add({
      name: Name,

    }).then(ref => {
      console.log('Added new user');
      console.log('ref id is:' + ref.id);

      admin.firestore().collection('users').doc('Details').collection('MYuser1').doc(ref.id).add({
        //here I'm using doc(ref.id) to get that document
        answer1: Answer1,
      })
    });
  }
});
```

I could able to add name into a subcollection using this code, But I'm trying to add answer1 next time into the same document inside the subcollection but it throws me error on this statement,

```
admin.firestore().collection('users').doc('Details').collection('MYuser1').doc(ref.id).add({
```

the error looks like:

[image]

And I am using api v1 bot!

Comment: Please don't show pictures of code and errors.  It's far better to copy the text into the question so that it's easier to read and search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `add()` method on a document reference.  This is your document reference:

```
admin.firestore().collection('users').doc('Details').collection('MYuser1').doc(ref.id)
```

With that, you're trying to call the `add()` method on it.  `add()` is for collections, and you use it to add a document to the collection.

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do on that line, since you already added the document previously.  If you have more fields to add to that document, it makes sense to add them all at the time time with the first time you called `add()` on the MyUser1 collection.

Comment: I have already created a document in a collection with only one field "name", Now I want to add other field say "Answer1" to the same document which has name field, For that I tried this query. I even tried adding all the fields at the same time whenn I added name but I am getting error like "unhandled rejection". So that I tried adding them one by one! like --->>admin.firestore().collection('users').doc('Details').collection('MYuser1').add({
                  name: Name ,
                  answer1 : Answer1
               }